# Algorithm to compare files and sub directories in main directory to the database

Tags: php, mysql, filesystems, directory

I need to update the file paths in a directory recursively in the database. Like if I made any changes in the directory, then that has to be updated in the database. What is the best and fastest way to do this using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: You might look at the [`Inotify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php) extension.

Answer (score 0):

In your MySQL database you must have these tables:

```
Directory{
    directory_id: integer;
    directory_name: varchar;
    directory_path: varchar;
    parent_id: fk_to_directoy_id;
}

File{
    file_id: integer;
    file_name: varchar;
    directory_id: fk_to_directory_id;
}
```

so you can build the hierarchical directory structure and then attach files to its directory.

Then you just need a backend in php to manage these tables. (Look to a framework to make it easy [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/))

Hope it helped you. Good luck.

Comment: actually I am using a similar structure in my database but the problem I am getting is on each update in the directory it is taking a lot of time to scan through all sub directories and storing the updates in database. The directory size runs into giga bytes and some files in are around 2GB itself. Also the directory is on remote server like DropBox. Currently I am using PHP's DirectoryIterator class to get the file paths from the directory and mapping that to the database for checking any update